# Complex Analysis: Graphing an equation

Tags: complex-analysis

$\left|z−1\right|+\left|z+1\right| = 2$

I want to sketch the equation and I recognize this equation as one that is probably an ellipse, but when I work all of the algebra out I end up with $y^2=0$ or a solution of $y=0$.  Thus, the graph i am getting is a straight line between $-1$ and $1$.  Thus, the equation is closed, bounded and connected.

Did I graph this equation correctly or have I mis-caluclated?

Answer (score 0):

Don't go straight to the equations.

You should be able to look at that equation and say "the distance between z and -1 PLUS the distance between z and +1 EQUALS 2"

So yes, you're right. You have a piece of string of length 2. you attach one end to -1 and the other end to +1.  You can then trace an ellipse with a pencil.